# BOOST_STATIC_WARNING

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-warnings

I've recently had some trouble with C++'s implicit casting, so I'm looking for a way to warn people if somebody attempts to assign an int32_t to a uint64_t or whatever.  `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT` would work wonders for this, except that the code base I'm working with is quite large and relies on a lot of implicit casting, so immediately breaking everything with assertions is unrealistic.

It looks like [BOOST_STATIC_WARNING](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/serialization/doc/static_warning.html) would be ideal for me, however, I cannot get it to actually emit a warning.  Something like this won't do anything:

```
    typedef boost::is_same<int64_t, int32_t> same_type;
    BOOST_STATIC_WARNING(same_type::value);
```

My compiler is g++ 4.4.3 with --std=c++0x -Wall -Wextra.  My Boost is 1.46.1.

---

The problem I'm trying to solve here is that we have a buffer type which has methods like `uint8_t GetUInt8(size_type index)`, `void SetUInt32(size_type index, uint32_t value)`, etc.  So, you see usage like this:

```
x = buffer.GetUInt16(96);
```

The problem is that there is no guarantee that, while you are reading a 16-bit unsigned integer, that `x` is actually 16-bits.  While the person who originally wrote that line did it properly (hopefully), if the type of `x` changes, this line will break silently.

My solution is to create a `safe_convertable<T>` type like so:

```
template <typename T>
struct safe_convertable
{
public:
    template <typename TSource>
    safe_convertable(const TSource& val)
    {
        typedef boost::is_same<T, TSource> same_type;
        BOOST_STATIC_WARNING(same_type::value);

        _val = val;
    }

    template <typename TDestination>
    operator TDestination ()
    {
        typedef boost::is_same<T, TDestination> same_type;
        BOOST_STATIC_WARNING(same_type::value);

        return _val;
    }
private:
    T _val;
};
```

and change the methods to return and accept these safe references: `safe_reference<uint8_t> GetUInt8(size_type index)`, `void SetUInt32(size_type index, safe_reference<uint32_t> value)` (that's the short version, there are other operators and whatnot you can do to references).

Anyway, this works great with `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT`, save for the fact that I want warnings and not errors.

---

For the curious, I've implemented the warning thing myself, which works fine, but I'd prefer the Boost variety so that I get all the other Boost features (this only works inside a function).

```
namespace detail
{
    template <typename TIntegralContant>
    inline void test_warning(const TIntegralContant&)
    {
        static_cast<void>(1 / TIntegralContant::value);
    }
}

#define MY_STATIC_WARNING(value_) \
    ::detail::test_warning(::boost::integral_constant<bool, value_ >())
```

Comment: "I cannot get it to actually emit a warning. Something like this won't do anything:"

Comment: @Nawaz: He wrote "I cannot get it to actually emit a warning".

Comment: @Travis: It is giving warning with `g++ 4.3.4` : http://www.ideone.com/68yOM ... since ideone doesn't have boost for `c++0x`, so I cannot compile it with `--std=c++0x` option.

Comment: Why do you want a warning, if you are not going to fix the problem? That's just added noice.

Comment: @Bo: I will fix the problem, I just don't want to break the builds in the mean time.  They are problems that need to be fixed, just not *immediately*.

Comment: @Travis - If you're not gonna fix it (now), don't bother. More warnings are just added noice!

Comment: Can I blame the spell checker? Noice is a swedish band :-) [http://www.noice.se/](http://www.noice.se/)

Comment: Bo: don't they (Noice) have one foot in the grave by now...?

Comment: can you post an example of what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Nawaz, doesn't work for me, G++ 4.6.1, with or without c++0x, on -O0, -O1, -O3, with or without -W -Wall

Comment: Edited with more explanation of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Boost are you using? This comment may be the reason why your own warning works, but the boost version does not:

```
// 6. replaced implementation with one which depends solely on
//    mpl::print<>.  The previous one was found to fail for functions
//    under recent versions of gcc and intel compilers - Robert Ramey
```

I'm guessing if you upgraded to a recent version of Boost (e.g. 1.46.1), you'd be good to go. *crosses fingers*

Comment: Doh! So much for that idea. Mind filing a bug?