# Include #warning within a macro to be evaluated later?

Tags: c++, macros

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does there exist a static_warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936063/does-there-exist-a-static-warning)

I often use #warning scattered through my code to mark places where I need to come back to.

Like:

```
#warning The blahblah hasn't been implemented yet; use foo to do so.
```

I'd like to instead create a macro that optionally doesn't show the warnings specifically related to my notes, but shows actual warnings from the compiler and other libraries.

Something like:

```
#ifdef SUPPRESS_NOTES
    #define BUILD_NOTE
#else
    #define BUILD_NOTE #warning Note: msg
#endif
```

Unfortunately, #warning gets evaluated first. Is there any way I can do this? I use GCC (MinGW).

Comment: In particular [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8990275/168175)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the TODO Makro from the [GCC online doc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html), here is what you want:

```
#define DO_PRAGMA(x) _Pragma (#x)
#define TODO(x) DO_PRAGMA(message ("TODO - " #x))
#ifdef SUPRESS_NOTES
#  define BUILD_NOTE
#else
#  define BUILD_NOTE DO_PRAGMA(message ("The blahblah hasn't been implemented " \
                                        "yet; use foo to do so."))
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't fig out how to make them resolve in the proper order.