# static_message or something like that

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does there exist a static_warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936063/does-there-exist-a-static-warning)

Is there a way to implement non fatal messages at compile time just like static_assert do when its condition fail? Having a message that shows up always when the compiler encounters it is not enough, I want it to show up when, for example, a template is instantiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would [BOOST_STATIC_WARNING](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/serialization/doc/static_warning.html) work for you?