# How to enable warnings on conversion from int to int64_t in gcc or clang

Tags: c++, g++, clang

Is it possible to enable warnings in g++ or clang on cast from int to int64_t?
Example:

```
int n;
cin >> n;
int64_t power = (1 << n);
```

I want that compiler tells me about this conversion in third line.

Comment: Why do you wan't a warning on an upcast?

Comment: The third statement is not syntactically valid, could you correct it please?

Comment: I assume you want the warning because `(1LL << n)` is what you actually want.

Comment: @NathanOliver, look for Loki Astari comment. This is a common mistake. When you write something like `int64_t memory_size = 2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;` and get overflowing. But in this case it will give you a warning, but in that case in the post - no warning.

Comment: @LokiAstari, yes, exactly!

Comment: Because it happens in so many places automatically a warning flag like that would generate a lot of noise. So I don't think it would be useful in the general case. So I don't believe there is one (I did try and google but nothing useful came up). You could create your own class to catch it I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build something on these lines:

```
struct my_int64
{
    template<class Y> my_int64(const Y&)
    {
        static_assert(false, "can't do this");
    }
    template<> my_int64(const long long&) = default;
    /*ToDo - you need to hold the data member here, and 
      supply necessary conversion operators*/
};
```

Then

```
int n = 3;
my_int64 power = (1LL << n);
```

compiles, but

```
my_int64 power = (1 << n);
```

will not. In that sense, this is a good starting point. You could hack the preprocessor to use this in place of `int64_t`.

If you wanted a warning rather than an error, you could replace the `static_assert` with

`my_int64 x{}; Y y = x;` and *hope* the compiler emits a warning for a *narrowing* conversion, and trust it to optimise out the two statements as they are collectively a no-op.

Comment: Yes, I like the idea. But probably static_assert isn't what I looking for, because I want just warning.

Comment: @SukhanovNiсkolay _"because I want just warning"_ Dude you are picky. I'm afraid you'll need to rewrite `static_assert()` to something like `static_assertion_warn()` that results in a compiler warning only. Have fun with that.

Comment: OK. It's a Friday. Pasted an idea up for that.

Comment: @SukhanovNiсkolay Here's some [more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936063/does-there-exist-a-static-warning) ... Was easy to find it :-P ...