# Compile time message testing constexpr

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr, static-assert

Is it possible to print a message when a test on a compile time constexpr evalates true? Something like static_assert without stopping the compiler.

```
constexpr Application::Mode SETUP_MODE = Application::Debug;

// Can I somehow test if the SETUP_MODE is debug for pragma message?
#pragma message("Application mode is set to Debug!")

static_assert(SETUP_MODE != Application::Debug, 
    "Application mode is set to Debug!"); // Can I somehow just print this message without aborting the compilation?
```

Comment: There is no standard mechanism for generating compiler messages that aren't errors. You'll need to rely on implementation specific features.

Comment: This certainly is non standard, so which compiler do you work with?

Comment: Mostly gcc, sometimes clang

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936063/does-there-exist-a-static-warning

Comment: @JamesRoot I'd say that's actually good enough as a dupe.