# `static_assert` like mechanism that throws warning instead of error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, g++, clang++

I would like to have an mechanism that works like `static_assert` (condition evaluated by compiler at compiletime (using `sizeof`)) but that throws warnings only.

Is there some mechanism  to achieve this in a compiler independent way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936063/does-there-exist-a-static-warning

Comment: You can slap one on your own in just a few lines worth of C++17 http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53573cfb9c31305b

Comment: @StoryTeller as far as i know, visual studio 2010 does not support the C++17 yet

Comment: Does it even support `static_assert`? If you are using an out of date compiler you should tag with the **standard version** you need.

Comment: @vlad_tepesch *yet*? VS 2010 doesn't even do C++11. Are you not able to upgrade to VS 2017?

Comment: @Asu the 'yet' was just a joke, because i had put 2010 it in the tags before. But the linked answer helps.