# Warn for function argument that is NOT a compile time constant

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings

Suppose I am maintaining a library function that takes two arguments, both pointers.  The second argument exists only for backward compatibility; callers should always pass a NULL. I would like to put something into my header file that makes the compiler issue warnings if the second argument is not a compile-time constant NULL.  I thought I would be able to do this using GCC's `__builtin_constant_p` and `__attribute__((warning))` extensions:

```
extern void thefun_called_with_nonnull_arg (void)
    __attribute__((__warning__(
        "'thefun' called with second argument not NULL")));

extern int real_thefun (void *, void *);

static inline int
thefun (void *a, void *b)
{
   if (!__builtin_constant_p(b) || b != 0)
       thefun_called_with_nonnull_arg();
   return real_thefun(a, b);
}

int warning_expected (void *a, void *b)
{
    return thefun(a, b);
}
int warning_not_expected (void *a)
{
    return thefun(a, 0);
}
```

But this doesn't work with any version of GCC I have tested.  I get warnings for *both* calls to `thefun`.  ([Compiler Explorer demo](https://godbolt.org/z/V-FHtZ).)

Can anyone suggest an alternative construct that will produce a warning for `warning_expected`, and not for `warning_not_expected` ?

Notes:

- Curiously, the above [*does* work](https://godbolt.org/z/rcpAug) if `b` is an `int`.
- The above uses GCC-specific extensions, however a solution that works on a broader variety of compilers would be welcome.  (In particular, clang does not implement `attribute((warning))` and I haven't had any luck finding an alternative.)
- A solution that still works when optimization is turned off would be preferable to one that doesn't.  (The above does not work with optimization turned off, even if `b` is an `int` and `thefun` is marked always-inline.)
- A solution that doesn't involve defining `thefun` as a macro would be preferable to one that does.
- The header has to work when included from C programs and from C++ programs.  A modest amount of ifdeffage is acceptable.
- It must be a warning, not a hard error, unless `-Werror` or equivalent is active.

---

**EDIT:** Based on [Kamil Cuk's discovery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57665148) that the unwanted warning can be suppressed by casting the pointer to an integer *of a different size*, I have determined that this is an oversight in the implementation of `__builtin_constant_p` and [filed GCC bug report #91554](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=91554).  I'd still be interested in answers that provide ways to do this with clang, icc, or any other compiler that's commonly used together with GNU libc.

Comment: `gettimeofday()`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler not sure about that: https://godbolt.org/z/TbCwpb

Comment: Have you tried `b!=(void *)0`?

Comment: I read: _"...does not return 1 when you pass a constant numeric value to the inline function unless you specify the -O option."_ (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.1.0/gcc/Other-Builtins.html)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You have correctly guessed my larger goal; this is in aid of finding a version of https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commitdiff;h=53df1cd2811b71aa4193cb250b95fc14b7f310a3 that actually works.

Comment: @zwol, are you by chance a glibc developer?

Comment: @JL2210 Innn my copious free time, yes.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936063/does-there-exist-a-static-warning

Comment: This is so similar to FORTIFY_SOURCE implementation ex. [memset check](https://github.com/kraj/glibc/blob/master/string/bits/string_fortified.h#L59). `I get warnings for both calls` - well because your condition is `!__builtin_constant_p(b) || b != 0`. So you get a warning when `b` is not(!) a constant expresion or when `b` is not zero. Did you mean to `__builtin_constant_p(b) && b != (void*)0`?

Comment: @KamilCuk The OP wants to warn when either `b` is not a constant or `b` is a constant but is not zero.

Comment: @KamilCuk Heh, yes, I _was_ cribbing from `string_fortified.h` when I originally wrote this code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally managed to get it to work:

```
if (!__builtin_constant_p((int)(uintptr_t)b) || b != 0) {
```

With this you get only one warning.

It seems that `gcc` can't do `__builtin_constant_p` on a pointer type. The `__builtin_constant_p(b)` always returns 0, so the warn function is always linked. Casting `b` to `int` strangely works. Although it looses precision in the pointer value, we don't care about it, cause we only check if it's a constant.

Comment: Why not just cast to `uintptr_t`?

Comment: Because it doesn't work. Casting to `long` or `long long` and `unsigned` fashions doesn't work either. Casting to `short`, `int` or `char` works. You can try it `__builtin_constant_p((long long)b)` will always be zero and gcc thinkgs it's a constant expression, you can even `static_assert(__builtin_constant_p((long long)b) == 0, "");`.

Comment: Oh, this is fun.  Your suggestion works correctly when GCC is "targeting" a CPU and ABI where `uintptr_t` is not the same size as `int`.  But if `uintptr_t` and `int` _are_ the same size, it doesn't work.  But `(short)(uintptr_t)` still works in that case.  Based on this I have managed to identify the function in the guts of GCC that isn't handling this case properly, and have filed a bug report (see edits to question).  I'm going to accept this answer after a little further testing.  Is "Kamil Cuk" the name you would like to be credited by in the commit history?

Comment: @zwol Wow, good job. "Kamil Cukrowski <kamilcukrowski@gmail.com>" would be nicer ; )

Comment: @JL2210 Yeah, if you can find an alternative to calling a function declared with `__attribute__((warning))`, that works on Clang, I'd be interested to see an alternative answer demonstrating it.  (Your existing answer is no good to me because this really cannot be a hard error.)

Comment: @zwol Try... `__attribute__((deprecated(message)))`.

Comment: @zwol Found it! See answer.

Answer (score 3):

**There is no way to do what you describe without GNU extensions.**

This portable approach gives a hard error (because `_Static_assert` requires a constant expression):

```
#define thefun(a, b) \
({ \
   _Static_assert(b == 0, \
       "'thefun' called with second argument not NULL"); \
   real_thefun(a, b); \
})
```

However, there is *one* fortified-style approach that works on both GCC and Clang:

```
extern void thefun_called_with_nonnull_arg (void)
    __attribute__((__deprecated__(
        "'thefun' called with second argument not NULL")));

extern int real_thefun (void *, void *);

static inline int
thefun (void *a, void *b)
{
   if (!__builtin_constant_p((unsigned short)(unsigned long)b) || b != 0)
       thefun_called_with_nonnull_arg();
   return real_thefun(a, b);
}

int warning_expected (void *a, void *b)
{
    return thefun(a, b);
}
int warning_not_expected (void *a)
{
    return thefun(a, 0);
}
```

Tested with GCC 8.3.0 and Clang 8.0.0.

See [GCC bug report #91554](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=91554) for more information about the need for the casts.