# How to pass raw string literals to [[deprecated(message)]] attribute?

Tags: c++, attributes, c++14, deprecated, rawstring

I want to pass a raw string literals to `[[deprecated(message)]]` attribute as the message. The message is used again and again. So I want to avoid code repeat.

First, I tried to use static constexpr variable.

```
static constexpr auto str = R"(
Use this_func()
Description: ...
Parameter: ...
)";

[[deprecated(str)]] 
void test1() {
}
```

I got the error "deprecated message is not a string". It seems that static constexpr variable isn't accepted by `[[deprecated(message)]]`.

I tried to define the row string literals as preprocessor macro.

```
#define STR R"(
Use this_func()
Description: ...
Parameter: ...
)"

[[deprecated(STR)]]
void test2() {
}
```

It works as I expected as follows on clang++ 8.0.0.

```
prog.cc:38:5: warning: 'test2' is deprecated: 
Use this_func()
Description: ...
Parameter: ...
 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    test2();
    ^
```

Demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/gN4iOrul8Y0F76TZ

But g++ 9.2.0 outputs the compile error as follows:

```
prog.cc:19:13: error: unterminated raw string
   19 | #define STR R"(
      |             ^
prog.cc:23:2: warning: missing terminating " character
   23 | )"
      |  ^
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/e62pQ2Dq9vTuG6Or

```
#define STR R"(  \
Use this_func()  \
Description: ... \
Parameter: ...   \
)"
```

If I add backslashes on the tail of each line, no compile error occurred but output message is different from I expected as follows:

```
prog.cc:38:11: warning: 'void test2()' is deprecated:   \\nUse this_func()  \\nDescription: ... \\nParameter: ...   \\n [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
```

I'm not sure which compiler works correctly.

Is there any way to pass the raw string literals variable/macro to `[[deprecated]]` attribute?

Comment: The real problem is how to define a macro to expand to a raw string literal

Comment: It seems like gcc's display issue, see [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Ro6Vel).

Comment: @康桓瑋, thank you. Even if we write raw string literal on ``[[deprecated()]]` directly, gcc outputs one line and escaped`\n`. I understand about that. Let's accept that limitation. But I still have the problem how to avoid code repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "raw string literal variable". There may be a variable which points to a string literal, but it is a *variable*, not the literal itself. The `deprecated` attribute does not take a C++ constant expression evaluating to a string. It takes a [string literal](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/lex.string): an actual token sequence.

So the most you can do is use a macro to contain your string literal. Of course, macros and raw string literals don't play nice together, since the raw string is supposed to consume the entire text. So the `\` characters will act as both continuations for the macro *and* be part of the string.

Comment: (not raw) string literals and `\` is well formed? See https://wandbox.org/permlink/sTxdWXCU4CvrALPd https://wandbox.org/permlink/iqfmPsQTWj8z5yBR. It is not elegant but I can avoid code repeat.

Comment: @TakatoshiKondo: Yes, you can put regular string literals in macros. It's only the parsing oddities of raw string literals that makes them not work well in a macro.